# Changing UITextField borderstyle in didEndEditing

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I want to highlight a uitextfield when a user is editing it, so I set my textfield's borderstyle default to UITextBorderStyleNone and use the uitextfields delegates as following:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleBezel];
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
}
```

The Bezel style gets set and rendered, but when the endediting is called, the none style is not applied.
I tried changing the none to another (say rounded rect), but that one does render properly.

Does anybody know how I can get this to work?

Comment: Had you got any solution for this problem? If Yes then plz share with me..

Comment: No sorry, I reported it to Apple as a bug and it seems to be a valid bug...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is a bug. Anyway, I've solved by using this code:

```
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
```

This isn't a very beautiful method, but it does the work until Apple fixes this issue.

Comment: How do we find out when or if Apple has fixed this?

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue also. From my testing it looked as if I could set it to any style other than `UITextBorderStyleNone`.

A workaround that worked for me at least was disabling and re-enabling the textfield as seen below:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    textField.enabled = NO;
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
    textField.enabled = YES;
}
```

I don't really like it but it works for now.

Comment: 5 years on and still a problem.

Comment: 7 years on and this is still required to fix the issue. Hat-tip to you, sir.