# Unable to set UITextField's borderStyle to None in UISearchBar

Tags: ios

I'm trying to remove the `textborderstyle` of the `UITextField` in a `UISearchBar`. I know that I'm getting reference to the correct object, as I'm able to change the `TextBorderStyle` to `RoundedRect` and see a visible change.

I've tried subclassing UISearchBar with the following code:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
  UITextField *searchField;
  NSUInteger numViews = [self.subviews count];
  for(int i = 0; i < numViews; i++) {
    if([[self.subviews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) { //conform?
        searchField = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
    }
  }
  if(!(searchField == nil)) {
    [searchField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
  }
  [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

I've also tried this inside a class:

```
UITextField *txtSearchField = [_searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
[txtSearchField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[txtSearchField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
```

Neither of these work. By default, it seems to have `UITextBorderStyleLine` if I manually set it to `None`. I unfortunately haven't been able to find a way to remove the border style. Does anyone know how to do this? I'm trying to figure this out since I need my search bar to look like a `UITextField`. I'm debating just switching to a `UITextField` behind the scenes at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty certain that the only way to achieve this is to subclass UISearchBar!

Try this code in your layoutSubviews method once you have subclassed it!

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
   UITextField *searchField;
   NSUInteger numViews = [self.subviews count];
   for(int i = 0; i < numViews; i++) {
      if([[self.subviews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) { //conform?
        searchField = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
      }
   }
   if(!(searchField == nil)) {
       searchField.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
       [searchField setBackground: [UIImage imageNamed:@"buscador.png"] ];
       [searchField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
   }

   [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

The question found here [remove the border of uitextfield in uisearchbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601402/remove-the-boarder-of-uitextfield-in-uisearchbar) answers your initial question!

You can also reference [How to customize apperance of UISearchBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201406/how-to-customize-apperance-of-uisearchbar) for more information!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Looks like you didn't see that I almost had this exact thing in the question itself (actually verbatim). I had removed the setbackground as I just needed a white background. The UITextField defaults to UITextBorderStyleLine if you don't reset the background image, which is where my issue was. I'm marking this technically as answered, but please actually read the question next time. :]

Comment: It's actually a bug in UITextField. In order to work around it, you can also set the border style to something else first, and then immediately afterwards set it to UITextBorderStyleNone. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971454/changing-uitextfield-borderstyle-in-didendediting

Answer (score 1):

Just not to overlook the comment (I just did, when I landed in this same issue and came to this question). If,programmatically, your UITextField's borderStyle does 'not' get set to UITextBorderStyleNone, then try setting the background or backgroundColor property of the UITextField 'before' setting its borderStyle! And it works!